# Call html page from WebApi, Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I used Asp.Net Identity and I implemented reset password, I send a link to user Email to reset password.

Here is the code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ForgotPassword")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
             return BadRequest("Either user does not exist or you have not confirmed your email.");
            }

            try
            {
                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                Url.Link("DefaultApi",
              new { controller = "Account/ConfirmEmail", userId = user.Id, code = code });

                  string callbackUrl = Url.Link("DefaultApi", 
                    new { controller = "Account/ManageAccount/reset-password", userId = user.Id, code = code });
                //string callbackUrl = Url.Link("Default", 
                  //  new { controller = "User/ManageAccount/reset-password", userId = user.Id, code = code });
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", 
                    "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError(ex);
            }

        }

        return BadRequest();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ManageAccount
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ManageAccount/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult ManageAccount(string id)
    {
        if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            string page = id + ".html";

           return Redirect(page);
        }
        return Redirect("Login.html");
    }




    // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ResetPassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
           // return Redirect("https://localhost:44342/Login.html");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        return InternalServerError();
    }
```

Here is webApiConfig:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new
        System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));


        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);


    }
}
```

Here is the link sent to email:(Look at its format) !

> >
>   http://localhost:7524/api/Account/ManageAccount/reset-password?userId=1011&code=vbGi%2FzN0oFjw6RLlFVuBHiyEz2rH%2FNaO7tc5Y7Y47vzKKC5aNgx9yzZLbHtMD1%2BVZYCot1dvRZSLupPUYcxpCW%2FIl4cJwAIxVjVYA1kxrIjobdrXVqHNMXJmTF5u6cc%2FJdA0uDlQzNjoG4%2Fcjfl3ToRxarZokxI3VN8TEvt1I2M%3D

and I got:
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: The browser won't make a `POST` request when you click on the link. It will make a `GET` request.

Comment: You are right, this was from my playing on code :)

Comment: Your route is not correctly defined

Comment: I updated the question can you check please

Comment: You still have the `[HttpPost]` attribute.. Read [this comment again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634792/call-html-page-from-webapi#comment97960841_55634792)

Comment: I think the problem is in this line  return Redirect(page); but I don't know if there is another way or another key word